# Linux ps Output Format Spec

Tags: linux, command, ps

I am using Java API to connect my Remote Machine so I can see the running processes.

One of the requirements is to be able to kill any of the processes.

Now I am executing command

`ps aux | grep java` which return list of the running processes.

eg.

```
root       330  0.2  0.0     0    0 pts/0    Z    08:42   0:11 [java]
```

Does anyone know what is the spec is used for above output ? I'll need to convert above line into an object where 330 will the process id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only intresseted in the pid of the processes with that name check [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep).

---

**Example:**

```
$ pgrep sshd
791
22956
23060
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
ps -ef | grep java | awk -F" " '{print $2}'
```

Or specify the format yourself (e.g. pid and command only):

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep java | awk -F" " '{print $1}'
```

If the command with arguments is need for grep:

```
ps -eo pid,command | grep java | awk -F" " '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu system, `ps` says it's in line with these standards:

> STANDARDS
>         This ps conforms to:
>
> ```
>  1   Version 2 of the Single Unix Specification
>  2   The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 6
>  3   IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition
>  4   X/Open System Interfaces Extension [UP XSI]
>  5   ISO/IEC 9945:2003</blockquote>
> ```

But you might consider offloading the problem to [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep), which is already maintained and already understands about process names and such. It gives you a much, much simpler output: By default, just the matching process IDs, one per line, like this:

```
$ pgrep apache
3990
22244
22388
22391
22476
```

Doesn't get easier to parse than that. If you need to see more, you might consider the `-l` flag:

```
$ pgrep -l apache
3990 apache2
22244 apache2
22388 apache2
22391 apache2
22476 apache2
```

Also consider looking at the [`/proc` filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), which is where `ps` looks for its data.